# Random gray screen while playing game

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I have a strange issue with my PC. When I play 3D games, sometime (not always) the screen just turn gray with vertical line while the computer seems to be still working. I though at first that the temperature of the GPU was the source, but it is not the case (temperature around 45 for both CPU and GPU and the problem happen).

I also have few other problems that kind of make me believe the source is the power. Often my Blackwidow keyboard works strangely with keys repeating an infinite number of time (until I unplug) or function not working. My M60 corsair also sometime stop tracking (while the buttons still work) and 95% of time it is while playing game (and pressing more than one buttons at the same time).

My computer:

- Intel i7 2600K
- Asus M5A97 R2.0
- Powercolor 1GB Radeon 6870
- 8 GB of DDR3 1866
- 2 hard drive (7200)
- 1 SSD Crucial M4 Sata 3
- 5 fans (one big coolmaster)

The PSU is an Antec 750 watts.

If remember calculating that 750 watts should be enough, was I wrong? Could it be the plug or anything else? Or something completely unrelated?

**Update**

Yesterday, I played Awesomenauts a simple 2D game that should really not be hard to run, and the bug happened twice in an hour. It never happened when playing Diablo 3 (which is still easy to run, but in 3D). For the information, it seems to heppen more often with some indie game that are usually easy to run.

**Update 24th of July**

I have run few test to stress the GPU, the CPU and the PSU. Nothing happen when running FurMark which is an intensive test. Also, I looked at the voltage and everything seems fine. I have only one last idea but do not know how I can test it (without buying the part)

1. Problem with the HDD

Comment: The graphical defects sound like a driver problem.  The keyboard problem sounds like your USB Hub is malfunctioning.

Comment: All drivers are up to date. The keyboard does the same thing whatever USB port I choose. It does not happen very often, most of the time it works perfectly fine and it is only with the special function keys (changing the backlight, macro command, forward a song, etc.)

Comment: It not working with macro keys points to a problem wth the supporting software.

Comment: Well, that might not be related with the main problem, but I though that giving more information might help in identifying the source

Comment: If you want to find out if its power ammount, I have done this trick before. run a CPU test and GPU test and copy HD data all at the same time. I think I used furmark and intelburn, while both of them will not be going 100% it was one quick way I could use as much power as possible.  The video grey screen does not sound like a power or HD problem at all. mabey a latency (data balked) issue.  If it was not a 3D game render screen i would wonder if there wasnt some "desktop/window" display occurance happening back in the background causing a blip